# Is there a standard algorithm to check if container A is a superset of container B?

Tags: c++, std

I was looking for a standard algorithm that, given two containers A and B, both with no duplicates, returns true if all the elements of A compares to true with an element of B. I used `std::all_of` with a predicate that checks membership in the other container, but I was wondering if there was a more elegant solution..

Comment: Are these containers sorted?  Do you care about duplicates?

Comment: Strictly speaking, an element of one container can't be contained in another container -- they are separate entities. Presumably what you want to know is whether each element of `A` is _equal_ to some member of `B`?

Comment: First pass check:  if container A contains more elements than B, then fast fail and `return false;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a STL algorithm to check if two containers contain same elements?

I suppose that you mean "elements that compare equal". One object can only be an element of one container (at least in case of all standard containers).

> i was looking for an std:: algorithm that given two containers A and B, returns true if all the elements of A are contained in B.

This question is different from the one in the title.

For the first, there `std::is_permutation`. However, for some container types, there are more efficient algorithms. For example, if the container is sorted (such as `std::set`), then you can simply compare for equality.

For the second, there's no general algorithm. If the containers are sorted, then you can use `std::includes`. Otherwise you can write an algorithm that sorts first, and then uses `std::includes`.

> I used std::all_of with a predicate that checks membership in the other container

If the larger container has fast lookup (such as unordered set), then this solution is good.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I will change the title, sorry

Comment: "...if the container is sorted _and has no repeated elements_..."

Answer (score 0):

[std::includes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/includes) does this provided both containers are sorted.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main() {

  std::vector< int > A = {1, 2, 3, 4, 7};
  std::vector< int > B = { 1, 2 ,3};
  std::vector< int > C = { 3, 4, 5};

  bool BinA = std::includes(A.begin(), A.end(), B.begin(), B.end());
  bool CinA = std::includes(A.begin(), A.end(), C.begin(), C.end());
  std::cout<< "B in A = " << BinA <<std::endl;
  std::cout<< "C in A = " << CinA <<std::endl;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/dnoM4xPbY

If you they are not sorted, and you can't/don't want to sort them, then I believe the all_of approach is about as efficient as possible.
If performance is critical I think sorting first is more efficient but you should check for your particular case.

Comment: No, the two containers are not necessarily sorted

Comment: Have updated to address the nonsorted case.

Comment: "If performance is critical I think sorting first is more efficient ." - that's a bold claim. Personally I think you could "insertion sort" the larger container as you go (possibly using a container of reference_wrapper), and traverse the smaller container.